# OpenGL C# Bad texture alignment / stretching

Tags: c#, opengl

I'm new to OpenGL and I've been fighting with a problem with texture misalignment/stretching. The texture is size of 256x256 and type is png.

On the left is a quad with 2 triangles with the correct texture,
on the right is a custom plane with 16 quads all triangulated.

[image]

As you can see from the picture the texture is not fitting in the faces correctly even though I should have all the UV's correctly assigned.

Here's a picture of all the vertices, UV's and how the faces are formed. (Open in new tab for bigger picture):

[image]

Below is the code snippet of how I Start and use my OpenGL View:

```
public void Start(){
        Glut.glutInit();
        Glut.glutInitDisplayMode(Glut.GLUT_DOUBLE | Glut.GLUT_DEPTH);
        Glut.glutInitWindowSize(_width, _height);
        Glut.glutCreateWindow("OpenGL View");

        //Gl.ReloadFunctions();

        texture = new Texture("water.png");

        //Define functions
        Glut.glutIdleFunc(OnRenderFrame);
        Glut.glutDisplayFunc(OnDisplay);
        Glut.glutMouseFunc(OnMouse);
        Glut.glutMotionFunc(OnMove);
        Glut.glutCloseFunc(OnClose);


        program = new ShaderProgram(VertexShader, FragmentShader);
        program["projection_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(0.45f,
            (float)_width / _height, 0.1f, 1000f));

        program.Use();

        Glut.glutSetOption(Glut.GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE, Glut.GLUT_ACTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION);
        Glut.glutMainLoop();
}

private static void OnRenderFrame()
    {
        Gl.Viewport(0, 0, _width, _height);
        Gl.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

        Gl.UseProgram(program);

        Gl.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
        Gl.BindTexture(texture);

        Matrix4 transform = Matrix4.CreateRotationY(yangle) * Matrix4.CreateRotationX(xangle)
                            * Matrix4.CreateTranslation(translationVector);

        program["model_matrix"].SetValue(transform);
        program["view_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.LookAt(
            new Vector3(0, 0, viewZoom), Vector3.Zero,Vector3.Up));

        //Bind Vertices and Vertex indices
        Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(_model, program, "vertexPosition");
        Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(_modelUV, program, "vertexUV");
        Gl.BindBuffer(_model);
        Gl.BindBuffer(_modelFaces);

        Gl.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, _modelFaces.Count, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt,
                        IntPtr.Zero);

        Glut.glutSwapBuffers();
    }

    public static string VertexShader = @"
in vec3 vertexPosition;
in vec2 vertexUV;

out vec2 uv;

uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
uniform mat4 view_matrix;
uniform mat4 model_matrix;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = projection_matrix * view_matrix * model_matrix * vec4(vertexPosition,1);
    uv = vertexUV;
}
";
    public static string FragmentShader = @"

uniform sampler2D texture;

in vec2 uv;

out vec4 fragment;

void main(void)
{
    fragment = texture2D(texture, uv);
}
";
```

I can't seem to pinpoint the problem, the UV's looks all good and even though if they were not correct, they shouldn't stretch and repeat the texture as so since they are in the range of 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the way I assigned UV's to Video card's memory.

This is how I had my model loading:

```
public void SetModel(Vector3[] modelVertices, int[] modelFaces, Vector2[] modelUV)
    {
        _model = new VBO<Vector3>(modelVertices);
        _modelFaces = new VBO<int>(modelFaces, BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer);
        _modelUV = new VBO<Vector2>(modelUV, BufferTarget.TextureBuffer);
    }
```

And this is how it's supposed to be:

```
public void SetModel(Vector3[] modelVertices, int[] modelFaces, Vector2[] modelUV)
    {
        _model = new VBO<Vector3>(modelVertices);
        _modelFaces = new VBO<int>(modelFaces, BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer);
        _modelUV = new VBO<Vector2>(modelUV);
    }
```

When I assigned the vectors to VBO with BufferTarget in TextureBuffer, it flipped out. Solution was to remove the parameter so the BufferTarget defaults to ArrayBuffer.

I also edited my rendering function by deleting binding the vertices for nothing:

```
private static void OnRenderFrame()
    {
        Gl.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

        Gl.UseProgram(program);


        Matrix4 transform = Matrix4.CreateRotationY(yangle) * Matrix4.CreateRotationX(xangle)
                            * Matrix4.CreateTranslation(translationVector);

        Gl.BindTexture(texture);

        program["model_matrix"].SetValue(transform);
        program["view_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.LookAt(
            new Vector3(0, 0, viewZoom), Vector3.Zero,Vector3.Up));


        Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(_model, program, "vertexPosition");
        Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(_modelUV, program, "vertexUV");

        Gl.BindBuffer(_modelFaces);


        Gl.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, _modelFaces.Count, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt,
                        IntPtr.Zero);

        Glut.glutSwapBuffers();

    }
```